# ploting 3D decision boundaries using SVM classification with 3 classes in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, svm, gaussian, multilabel-classification

I am studying examples in Matlab to try to understand the classification procedure for Gaussian SVM. Does anyone have some code in MATLAB (i am using the classification learner app) where I can plot in 3 D the decision boundaries for a multi-label classification?

Comment: SVM is binary classification, You can find plot 2D decision boundary in MATLAB help.

Comment: Thanks PyMatFlow, I have implemented the examples from Help. I would like to plot decision boundaries for a multi - label classification (not binary). Maybe i do not understand well if this can be done, or if it will be many binary classification problems. Thanks again for your proposal